# Countdown Timer with Input Field

Tags: jquery, html, refresh, countdown, jquery-countdown

I'm sure someone already figured this out, but I couldn't seem to have found it on my end.

What I have is a pretty basic countdown where a user puts the amount of minutes into the input field, click the button, and it counts down the minutes.

What I would like to know is for *just the countdown* to *ignore* the page when it refreshes (to just continue on as it was).  At the moment, it just stops the countdown.

Here is what I have so far.

HTML:

```
<form>
<input id="tminus" placeholder="0:00"></input>
<input id="request" placeholder="Enter Minutes here"></input>
<a href="#" class="button enterTime">Submit Time</a>
 <input type="reset" value="Clear form" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('.enterTime').click(function () {
    var reqVal = $('#request').val();
    var parAmt = parseInt(reqVal);
    var totalAmount = parAmt * 60;
     $('#request').val(" ");

    var timeloop, timeSet = function () {

        totalAmount--;

        var minutes = parseInt(totalAmount/60);
        var seconds = parseInt(totalAmount%60);

        if(seconds < 10)
            seconds = "0"+seconds;
        $('#tminus').val(minutes + ":" + seconds);
    };

    var timeloop  = setInterval(timeSet, 1000);

})
```

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: as you are counting down in seconds. save the amount of seconds left in local storage or a cookie on each tick. then `$(document).ready`, see if its set and if it is, start your time from the seconds left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save `totalAmount` to `localStorage` and get value from there when user refreshes the page. Heres around what you need:

### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6n2xyg7j/)

```js
// Get totalAmount from localStorage and if there is positive value call timeSet() immediately
var totalAmount = localStorage.getItem('countDown') || 0,
    timeloop;

if (totalAmount) {
    timeSet()
}

function timeSet () {
    totalAmount--;
    // Refresh value in localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('countDown', totalAmount);

     // If countdown is over, then remove value from storage and clear timeout
     if (totalAmount < 0 ) {
         localStorage.removeItem('countDown');
         totalAmount = 0;
         clearTimeout(timeloop);
         return;
     }

    var minutes = parseInt(totalAmount/60);
    var seconds = parseInt(totalAmount%60);

    if(seconds < 10)
        seconds = "0"+seconds;

    $('#tminus').val(minutes + ":" + seconds);

    timeloop = setTimeout(timeSet, 1000);
}

$('.enterTime').click(function () {
    var reqVal = $('#request').val();
    var parAmt = parseInt(reqVal);

    if (timeloop) {
        clearTimeout(timeloop)
    }

    totalAmount = parAmt * 60;

    $('#request').val(" ");

    timeSet();
})

// Clear timeout and remove localStorage value when resetting form
$('#countdown').on('reset', function () {
    totalAmount = 0;
    clearTimeout(timeloop);
    localStorage.removeItem('countDown');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="countdown">
    <input id="tminus" placeholder="0:00" />
    <input id="request" placeholder="Enter Minutes here" />
    <a href="#" class="button enterTime">Submit Time</a>
    <input type="reset" value="Clear form" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer and providing a solution.